# What would be the quickest way to find the maximum of four numbers if we can only edit the body of the function?

Tags: c++

I am new to to C++
Input and output are handled by the system, we can only manipulate the body of the function max_of_four() to get our o/p.

this is how i solved,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int max = a;
    if(b>a)
    {
        if (c>b)
        {
            if(d>c)
            {
                max = d;
            }
            else 
            {
                max = c;
            }
        }
        else if(d>b)
        {
            max = d;
        }
        else
        {
           max = b;
        }
    } 
    else if(c>a) 
    {
        if(d>c)
        {
            max =d;
        }
        else
        {
            max = c;
        }
    } 
    else if(d>a)
    {
        max = d;
    }
    else
    {
        max = a; 
    }
    return max;
}

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);

    return 0;
}
```

we can check efficiently as we get inputs one by one, but in this case, we cannot touch the main block but only the function block. The way I have solved seems too much manual. Is there a quicker way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::max()` function:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return max(a,max(b,max(c,d)));
}
```

But if you restricted to not use any built-in functions (sometimes I restrict my student to not use any built-in functions) another solution without `max()` function is by saving the temporary maximum value and then iterate to all variables:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int max = a;
    if(b>max) max = b;
    if(c>max) max = c;
    if(d>max) max = d;

    return max;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @malioboro, simple and educational, seems like I have a long way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest is perhaps that:

```
/* cout, assign or return it */  std::max({a, b, c, d});
```

If it also is most efficient or not depends on qualiy of implementation of the standard library that you use.

Comment: I am still getting exposed to standard library functions. I agree it is the most efficient way to solve the problem. thank you for sharing.

Comment: @SubashGowthaman The standard library and C++ core language are regulated with same, single standard. To learn C++ one has to learn both.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about quicker, but here's a much simpler implementation.

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
   int max1 = a > b ? a : b;
   int max2 = c > d ? c : d;

   return (max1 > max2 ? max1 : max2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @R Sahu, so simple and precise.

Answer (score 0):

Post C++11, the best way is to use the *initializer list* notation and write

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
std::max({a, b, c, d});
```

Due to the interactions between the C++ standard library and compiler, this may well end up being the fastest solution too.